# Background Images with Ratchet

Tags: ratchet-2

What is the recommended way to add a background image to the body (more precisely .content) of a ratchet-based app? The ios theme feels a little plain to me.. is it bad practice to give an app a background image?

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it is working well for me on iOS ( even iPad ) and Android.

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background-image: url("../img/background-mobile.jpg");
  background-position: center top;
  z-index: 1
}
```